# Finding the tangents of the function in each mesh

Tags: plotting, vector, mesh

I have a 2D graphic which contains a table of curves within a circular region.

```
rotateparametric[parfunc_, fixedpoint_, angle_] := 
  RotationMatrix[angle].(parfunc - fixedpoint) + fixedpoint;
viewAngle = Pi/3;
ctrVolume = {(Exp[(Pi - viewAngle)*0.5] + 1)/2, 0};
radiusVolume = (Exp[(Pi - viewAngle)*0.5] - 1)/2;
radiusRing = (Exp[(Pi - viewAngle)*0.5] + 1)/2;
FPS = 120*3;
fPlanet = 3; 
fOrbit = 10;
radiusEquation = Exp[t*0.5];
planetRotation = 
 rotateparametric[{radiusEquation*Cos[t], radiusEquation*Sin[t]}, {0, 
   0}, -2*Pi*i*fPlanet/FPS]
mirrorPlanetRotation = 
 rotateparametric[{radiusEquation*Cos[t], radiusEquation*Sin[t]}, {0, 
   0}, Pi - 2*Pi*i*fPlanet/FPS]
orbitRotation = 
 rotateparametric[planetRotation, ctrVolume, -2*Pi*i*fOrbit/FPS]
mirrorOrbitRotation = 
 rotateparametric[planetRotation, ctrVolume, Pi - 2*Pi*i*fOrbit/FPS]
TheCurves = Evaluate@Table[orbitRotation, {i, 1, FPS}];
TheMirrorCurves = Evaluate@Table[mirrorOrbitRotation, {i, 1, FPS}];
pp = ParametricPlot[{TheCurves, TheMirrorCurves}, {t, 0, 
   Pi - viewAngle}, 
  RegionFunction -> (Norm[{#, #2} - ctrVolume] <= radiusVolume &), 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

This is the output:

[image: curves]

What I want to do is first, divide the region into discrete little regions (meshes) which I will be the decider to the size of the mesh. For example like in below:

[image: mesh in detail]

Then I need to extract the tangent values of each curve within the mesh so I can calculate its perpendicular vectors angle as below:

[image: mesh tangent]

If it will be help, I need this to calculate the minimum voxel in a holographic volume. When I find the perpendicular vectors angle I will know the total view angle of the voxel (mesh). If the total angle covers 360 degree than it means I hit my goal. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the tags "finite-element-method". Please clarify.

Comment: i want to divide the region into meshes. if we talk about mesh don't also talk about finite element analysis?

Comment: "if we talk about mesh don't also talk about finite element analysis?" Nope. Finite element analysis is a method to solve partial differential equations.

Comment: I've read your question several times by now and I still have no clue what you want to do there. No clear aims, no example output, unclear definition of what you mean by "perpendicular vectors angle". _That_ might be the reasons why you haven't got a complete answer yet. Also, notice that this is not a free coding service.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I wll try to make it more clear. You are right, 'perpendicular vectors angle' is a weird description but I couldn't find an exact term for it so I drew to explain what I meant. I will try to make it more clear. However, I am offended by your accusation. Mathematica only compiles scripts. Without a code, suggesting short operations like 'use this table', 'try to use this function' are useless. Because If I knew how to write them I wouldn't ask this question. Every answer here has code in it. And I don't think the answer providers think what they re doing is free coding service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a full answer...

Look at a single curve, and discretize it. Also set a bounding box

```
curve = Table[TheCurves[[1]], {t, 0, Pi - viewAngle, π/1000}];

left = 2; right = 4; low = .2; high = 1;

ListPlot[curve, Epilog -> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{left, low}, {right, high}]}]
```

[image]

Now compute tangents to the curve using finite differencing

```
arctans = ArcTan @@@ Normalize /@ Differences[curve];
```

This list is 1 element shorter than your discretized curve, so drop the last element from your curve list.

```
shortCurve = Most@curve;
```

You can pick off the location of points that are in a voxel with a function

```
pointsInVoxel[left_, right_, low_, high_, curve_] := 
             Position[curve, {x_, y_} /; (left <= x <= right && low <= y <= high)]
```

Tying it together

```
locations = pointsInVoxel[left, right, low, high, shortCurve]

ListPlot[{curve, Extract[shortCurve, locations]}, 
 Epilog -> {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{left, low}, {right, high}]}]
```

[image]

```
Extract[arctans, locations] // ListPlot
```

[image]